# Creating block devices for openstack deployment using MAAS and juju (nova-volume deployment)

Tags: juju, maas, xen, openstack

I'm currently trying to get a openstack deployment working by using MAAS with 9 nodes and juju. To do this I found [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure), working with ubuntu 12.04 LTS and followed it as good as I can.

After a vigorous amount of trial and error I finally got to the point where I'm supposed to deploy nova-volume using the "custom" config file. However, when my node is started and shows up as running in the `juju status` report the service reports the installation failed. I'm trying to install with juju jitsu by the way. I think it has something to do with the following statement in the `openstack.cfg` file:

```
nova-volume:
# This must be a free block device that is writable on the nova-volume host.
block-device: "xvdb"
overwrite: "true"
```

I did some research and found that (at least I think) this refers to a Xen Virtual Drive/Device, and because the device is not present on the node it's being deployed to, the installation fails. What I don't understand is how am I supposed to have such a block device available on a machine which was completely managed by MAAS. Does anyone here have any experience with this and knows of a way to solve this or am I missing something big here. Some kind of missing link between the MAAS and a separate XEN host? My MAAS server is running Ubuntu 12.04LTS Server.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the block device to be a file location.
If you look at the nova-volume charm readme here:
http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/nova-volume

You can see that you can set the block device to /path/to/file[|size]

So, you can configure your openstack.cfg file with something like:

```
nova-volume:
    # This must be a free block device that is writable on the nova-volume host.
    block-device: "/var/lib/nova-volume/volume-1.img|100G"
    overwrite: "true"
```

This avoids the necessity to have a separate hardware device, but of course, is not ideal for a high performance production environment.